# How to disable spatial index creation by ArcSDE for Oracle Spatial

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, spatial-index

Working with ArcSDE 10.1 and Oracle spatial 11g.

I set the feature class in load_only_io before loading shapefiles. I am using geoprocessing tool (append) in ArcGIS to load shapefile to geodatabase. After loading ArcGIS is creating spatial index on sdo_geometry.

How to disable this automatic index creation?

I want to load shapefiles and later I want to create index myself.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to include the exact methodology you are using to populate the table.

Answer (score 1):

As per Documentation:

> With ArcSDE, putting a feature class in load-only mode disables
>   updating of the spatial index while data is loading. In a File
>   Geodatabase, putting a feature class or table in load-only mode
>   disables updating of spatial and attribute indexes while data is
>   loading. Taking the feature class or table out of load-only mode
>   rebuilds the indexes.

Therefore to prevent from index rebuild (or creation), don't take your FC out of load-only mode. After loading all the features, turn off the load-only mode.

If you don't like this behavior, you should manually drop any spatial indexes and insert all rows/features and then create the index manually yourself.

Comment: I am not taking FC out of load_only mode, but it creates spatial index

Comment: With load-only-mode, you need to acquire a schema lock (ISchemaLock). once you release the lock, load only mode will be turned off!

Comment: I am loading shape file using append geoprocessing tool

Comment: Any suggestions on this problem ??